# Returning sum of group of rows with each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Can the sum of column values for rows meeting selection criteria be returned not only with each individual row but for multiple groups meeting the same criteria?

For example, consider:

```
id  order_id    quantity
1   1           1
2   1           3
3   1           5
4   2           2
5   2           4
```

What MySQL SELECT query could return the follow results:

```
id  order_id    quantity    order_sum
1   1           1           9
2   1           3           9
3   1           5           9
4   2           2           6
5   2           4           6
```

EDIT:
follow-up question: assuming the results are produced from a query with multiple conditions, how would these conditions be handled in the final query?

Comment: Do you need the order_sum to actually be a column?

Comment: In most other modern DBMS's, you could use analytic functions to do this. MySQL lacks the SUM() analytic function, so Andomar's answer with a self-join on a subquery seems to be the next best thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a subquery in the "from" clause:

```
select  t.*, tsum.sumquantity
from t join
     (select t.orderid, sum(quantity) as sumquantity
      from t
      group by t.order_id
     ) tsum
     on t.orderid = tsum.orderid
```

The advantage of putting it in the "from" clause is that you can have multiple variables.  For instance, you could add the number of orders, the maximum quantity, the number of times exactly 1 quantity appears, and so on.

Comment: I want to use same thing like sum of data which are on same date. Is it possible to use same thing because it will have different id for all.
Also I want to use sum for all column in table.

Comment: @DaminiSuthar . . . *Ask a question* with the specifics of your problem.  You have started the process very well by doing research to see if there is a related question that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery:

```
select  *
,       (
        select  sum(quantity)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.order_id = yt1.order_id
        ) as order_sum
from    YourTable yt1
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a subquery that will compute the `SUM` of the `quantity` for each `Order_ID`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.order_sum
FROM    myTable a INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT order_ID, 
                       SUM(quantity) order_sum
                FROM    myTable
                GROUP BY order_ID
            ) b on a.order_ID = b.order_ID
```